# Zapier Results from `triggers.new_booking.operation.perform` must be an array of objects

Tags: javascript, zapier

I am building a zapier integration for an app. The app returns a JSON response like this...

```
{
  result: "Success",
  message: "Showing a total of 1 bookings",
  bookings: {
    42: {
      event: {
        event_name: "Chris's Event",
        event_date_uk: "Saturday 22nd Jun 2019"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In my zapier parser, I have the following....

```
const options = {
  url: bundle.authData.url+`/api/v1/bookings`,
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json'
  },
  params: {
    'key': bundle.authData.api_key,
    'secret': bundle.authData.client_secret,
    'booking_id': 42,
    'scope': 'full'
  },
}

return z.request(options)
  .then((response) => {
    response.throwForStatus();
    const results = z.JSON.parse(response.content);

    return results["bookings"];

  });
```

However, when I test, I get the following....

Results from `triggers.new_booking.operation.perform` must be an array of objects. We got `{"42": {"event": {"event_name": "Chris's Event", "event_date_uk": "Saturday 22nd Jun 2019"}}}`.
[image]

I thought JSON.parse did return an object? And from what I can see I have returned an array of objects. Any ideas what Im doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This contains an *array* of objects (bookings):

```
{
  "result": "Success",
  "message": "Showing a total of 1 bookings",
  "bookings": [
    {
      "42": {
        "event": {
          "event_name": "Chris's Event",
          "event_date_uk": "Saturday 22nd Jun 2019"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Edit: To access the event property in your JSON it's `bookings.42.event` where in JSON above it's `bookings[0].42.event`.

Comment: But i am returning only the bookings... return results["bookings"]; and the error is saying I should return an array of objects, which is what im doing?

Comment: No. Your JSON doesn't have any array of bookings.

Comment: smh. Thank you. Time for another coffee!

Comment: const result = Object.values(results["bookings"]) sorted it

Comment: Glad to help you